# WebSocket build configuration for STOMP/SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I try to create endpoints `/api/streams/positions` and `/api/streams/orders` but confused with configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/api/streams");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("streams");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/streams/positions", "/api/streams/orders")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}

    
@Controller("/api/streams")
public class WebSocketController {
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/positions")
    public void positionsSendToBrowserAuthenticatedClient(PositionDto position) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user.getUsername(),"/streams/position", position);
    }
}
```

What is the configuration I need for the controller work? And what is `enableSimpleBroker()` and `setApplicationDestinationPrefixes()` actually means? Can I have one endpoint to get and send messages at the same time?

**UPDATE_1 +DTO**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PositionDto {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private PositionType type;

    @JsonProperty("openAt")
    private Timestamp openAt;

    @JsonProperty("openPrice")
    private BigDecimal openPrice;

    @JsonProperty("orders")
    private List<OrderDto> orders;
}


public enum PositionType {
    LONG("LONG"), SHORT("SHORT");

    public final String value;

    PositionType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I could help because it seems that you're building a kind of trading application, but need more informations: are you building a websocket yourself or do you want to get data from an existing one to build a DTO?

Comment: I add DTO I will be grateful for the help. I'm building a WebSocket yourself in this case my desktop app with JS will connect to this endpoint.

Comment: Here is a perfect tutorial to halp: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ But to help, did you try to get the data from your websocket inside a frontend or something?

Comment: Yes, I couple of hours trying to make my task by this tutorial but can't catch what is result endpoint author build? `ws://hello`? I need to send something to `ws://hello` for listening? What mean `@SendTo("/topic/greetings")`

Answer (score 1):

The SendTo is like an transmitter. You just have to "subscribe" to this ws like this, for an angular application's service (for example):

```
getTestnetCurrentPrice(symbol: string): Observable<any> {
    const subject = webSocket(`wss://YOURWEBSOCKETADRESS?param=${param}`);

    return this.http.get(`https://YOURWEBSOCKETADRESS?param=${param}`);
  }
```

You can also test your websocket with a simple const like that:

```
const yourSocket = new WebSocket('wss://YOURWEBSOCKETADRESS' + this.param());
```

You can find a lot of good tutorials with cryptocurrencies plateform who will help you.

Here is an example of a front Angular financial service example dedicated to a websocket:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CandlecollectService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://YOURBACKENDPOINT/';
  obj: any;
  object: JSON;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  extractCandles(symbol: string, interval: string, limit: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${symbol}/${interval}/param`);
  }

  getCurrentPrice(symbol: string): Observable<any> {
    const subject = webSocket(`wss://YOURWEBSOCKETURL?symbol=${symbol}`);

    return this.http.get(`https://YOURWEBSOCKERURL?symbol=${symbol}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is understood, but how YOURWEBSOCKETADRESS from your example build in `registry.addEndpoint("/what") config.enableSimpleBroker("/streams/"); config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app") @MessageMapping("/position")` how it connect?

Comment: If you websocket is correctly configured, you just have to subscribe to the adress and display the datas. Which kind of application do you use for the frontend?

Comment: yes this endpoint will use Angular frontend in its own container now I need to build an endpoint to connect and receive data from the backend when the backend wants to push.

Comment: Ok, it's a little bit confusing but you're talking about a front service. Here is an example of a front angular service dedicated to a webSocket. Just look at my precedent message

Comment: I know how to make it in angular my question is how to build the correct path `/api/streams/positions` with spring annotation